# Converting DateTime? value to Date in MVC 3 view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have an MVC3 application with a model that contains a DeployedDate property of the type DateTime?. In my view I want to only show the date in the text box but not the time.

```
<%: Html.EditorFor(model => model.DeployedDate) %>
<%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DeployedDate) %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are open to modify Model, You can use [DisplayFormatAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayformatattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). You can specify [ApplyFormatInEditMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayformatattribute.applyformatineditmode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
public DateTime? DeployedDate{ get; set; }
```